# Exporting numpy array + String to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two numpy array, each shaped (x,1). I wanted to export the data to CSV file so it looks something like this

Channel- Freq(np Array 1) - FFT(np Array 2) - Class (a string label)

Channel and class column will have 1 fixed value, freq and FFT comes from the array.

I have tried using np.column_stack but that only allows combining freq and fft, nothing else. I have tried looking at pandas DataFrame (which the original data comes from after importing from CSV) I can't find anything useful at the moment.

```
def combine_data(freq, matrix):
    combine_dt = np.column_stack((freq, matrix))
    return combine_dt

def export_data_csv(freq, matrix):
    combined_data = np.column_stack((freq, matrix))
    np.savetxt("freq_amp.csv", combined_data, delimiter=",")
```

This only works to make a CSV with only two columns

Comment: Have you tried numpy.hstack? This allows you to stack two columns together horizontally. You then then write to a csv normally.

Comment: Given small examples of your arrays, and the desired output.  How picky are you about the format and spacing of the numeric columns? `column_stack` can join 3 arrays.

Comment: so the data I need to export will have more columns, It will have e.g. Channel - Frequency - FFT.real() - FFT.imag() - Class, a channel is just 1-4 (one of the channel numbers), class is just what the input signal was to generate the original data, e.g. a frequency of 50Hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easier using pandas.

Let's say:

```
array1=[0,1,2,3,4]
array2=[10,11,12,13,14]
```

First create a dataframe with the 2 arrays and then set the constant values:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={"freq":array1,"FFT":array2})
my_df["channel"]="channel_name"
my_df["class"]="class_name"

#Output
    freq    FFT     channel     class
0     0     10   channel_name   class_name
1     1     11   channel_name   class_name
2     2     12   channel_name   class_name
3     3     13   channel_name   class_name
4     4     14   channel_name   class_name
```

then you can easily export it to csv:

```
my_df.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

if you don't want/need the index just set:

```
my_df.to_csv("filename.csv",index=False)
```

For other options just look at the documentation [pandas.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)